# Cant GET/ problem with express routes an localhost

Tags: node.js, express

I watched a video by traversy media on youtube and after trying copying 1 for 1 his code i still didnt have any success with the problem. the code is suppose to route the main page('/') to the page(/routes/api/posts'), can anyone find the problem with my code?
my index.js code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');

app.use('/api/posts', posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started on port ' + port));
```

Posts.js page:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const router = express.Router();

//Get Posts
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
 res.send('hello');
});

//Add Post


//Delete Post

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks and sorry for the bad english :(

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j55fHUJqtyw

Comment: You have only defined one route, for `http://localhost/api/posts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.send('hello')` is only accesible through `GET /api/posts`. You shoulduse:

```
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');
app.use('', posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, there’s no routing from route `/` to route `/api/posts/`
Right now, express don’t know the route `/` because you have not defined it. That’s why it’s returning you a 404 error code, you should create a `/` route with the router to prevent this issue

Comment: can you please explain how i create a / route?

Comment: Just like the `/api/posts/` route. You invoke a router, and then, you define a GET route with ˋ/`